# How do I perform a shell execute in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, shellexecute

I'm not finding a way to do this in the chrome.* API or even the experimental. It doesn't run through wscript so 
`ActiveXObject("Shell.Application")` isn't allowed.

I fear that my only option is to build a dll with NPAPI but I wanted to see if there was a simpler way.

Comment: If you actually managed to succeed, in what sense would Chrome be sandboxed anymore?

Comment: @Kirk, well, you can use NPAPI plugins within extensions to go outside the sandbox.

Comment: @Mohamed, Yikes, that's interesting.  Does Chrome provide any special warning when an extension is being installed with such excess privileges?

Comment: @Kirk, well it goes to an approval process first which might take some time. Perfoming shell operations is a risky operation :) And only NPAPI can do risky stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to do anything Natively, you need to use NPAPI. That allows you to run code outside the sandbox for your extensions.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Comment: Looks like my only tool is a "hammer". Bummer, but it might do the job. thanks.

Comment: There must be some NPAPI plugins out there already :) Try looking at this: http://goo.gl/SzUp

Comment: Also, Chrome ended support for NPAPI.

Answer (score 15):

To update this for a fellow wary lonesome traveler, even NPAPI is deprecated and being phased out. One of the alternatives mentioned in [the NPAPI deprecation blog post](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation) that looks suitable for this type of problem (and pretty nifty really) is the [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) API.

Comment: Important caveat of this approach: unlike NPAPI plugins, Native Messaging hosts cannot be bundled with the extension in Chrome Web Store.

Comment: The current link to the Native Messaging API doc is: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you might want to have two applications:

1. a "client" that works within a chrome extension and
2. a "local server" where the actual command is executed.

Whenever the extension needs to execute a command, it can connect to the local server via tcp connection.

Comment: @penduDev, unfortunately, I don't have any code to share -- just the abstract idea.