# How to browserify a Node.js WebSocket server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Using examples from [node-chromify](https://github.com/iceddev/node-chromify) I managed to run a Node.js Http server on a client side - inside a Chrome browser.

Then I tried to do exactly the same with a WebSocket server. Unfortunately I failed. 
I think I tried most of the popular WebSocket libraries (npm modules) from Github.

While they work fine in configurations:

```
(a) both a WebSocket server and a WebSocket client are started from a Node command line
(b) the server runs from the command line and the client is included as a JavaScript in a html page (runs on a client side)
```

the scenario

```
(c) both the WebSocket server and the client running in a browser
```

is still unattainable for me so far.

During my attempts I tried the same approach by calling a command:

```
browserify server-ws.js -o bundle-server-ws.js
```

but when I included the generated bundle file into a html page I got always some critical errors regarding missing object definitions, etc.
In other words the above command seems not to bundle everything as the server code would expect during a runtime.

Should I use different switches/options during calling `browserify`?

Maybe it is not possible for `browserify` at all? For a client OK but with a server not...

I realize that migrating WebSocket stuff to the client side is much more complicated process than a regular npm module.

`browserify v. 2.36.1`

`Node 0.10.22`

Comment: can you please elaborate on `I managed to run a Node.js Http server on a client side - inside a chrome browser`. not sure I understand. technically, as far as I know - browsers do not have the permission to occupy a socket, so seems to me like what you're trying to achieve - running a server on the client side -  is not possible

Comment: @guymograbi, sorry for the very late response.. Please see the section "Testing the example" in the https://github.com/iceddev/node-chromify

Comment: @gvlax It's impossible to browserify websocket server, because there's no such thing available in client-side javascript. The closest thing I can think of is WebRTC.