# Is it possible to use npm packages in Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, npm, google-chrome-extension

Since lot of js modules are in npm now a days. I was wondering if there is any way to use them directly in making of a chrome extension.

Comment: The extension must include all of its files in the package. Just add a build step.

Comment: So does that mean its possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to require npm modules in a chrome extension ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684452/is-it-possible-to-require-npm-modules-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: I add answer on similar question. Look at
[stackoverflow.com/a/74680479/19502363](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74680479/19502363)

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible to use npm packages but they need to be bundled i.e. included in the extension javascript source. What you need to look into is a module bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) to create a bundle for your background scripts and/or content scripts along with the required npm packages. Your manifest should point to your bundled files and it should be working fine.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/Acesmndr/chrome-extension-boilerplate-riot/blob/master/src/popup/plugins/route.js)

Comment: Could you give an example. I didn’t quite understand