# Importing npm modules into Google Chrome Extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, npm, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I am a big noob learning chrome extension developement.

How in the world do you import npm packages into your content scripts or the background service worker.

For example If I want to use the [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/) object to parse and scrape some html within the document in a normal script I would use

```
//script.js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
```

I've come across many stack overflow questions and some of them said to use a bundler for all the packages, but I couldn't find any examples for implementing it in manifest v3.

I am using manifest **v3** and I have tried looking for examples, but they're all in manifest **v2**.

I've tried to understand how [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) works and from my understanding it takes an input file, *index.js*, then after you do the webpack build command it outputs a *main.js* file with all the assets and scripts into one (I may be understanding this process incorrectly).

How do I correctly use this output, *main.js*, webpack file into the chrome extension manifest?

Any examples will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43684769/437393

Comment: ManifestV3 didn't change anything substantial in this regard so the same solutions still apply, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48104433).