# Required module doesn't work on chrome extension script

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to extension development and not good at bundlers so I'm using [chrome-extension-webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/samuelsimoes/chrome-extension-webpack-boilerplate) to start developing my extension.

I want to make a simple timer extension, so after following the bolirplate repository's instructions, I downloaded a module called [tiny-timer](https://github.com/mathiasvr/tiny-timer) with `yarn add tiny-timer`. Then changed the `popup.html` and `popup.js` (added code from the tiny-timer repo that works fine on [RunKit](https://npm.runkit.com/tiny-timer)).

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Chrome Timer Extension",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon-34.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

popup.js

```
import "../css/popup.css";
const Timer = require("tiny-timer");
console.log(Timer);
const timer = new Timer();
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="timer"></h1>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <button id="continue">Go</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Popup output:

```
Module
    >default: class Timer
    Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
    __esModule: true
    >[[Prototype]]: Object

Uncaught TypeError: Timer is not a constructor
    at eval (popup.js?dffe:3)
    at Module../src/js/popup.js (popup.bundle.js:1271)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.bundle.js:727)
    at fn (popup.bundle.js:101)
    at Object.0 (popup.bundle.js:1286)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.bundle.js:727)
    at popup.bundle.js:794
    at popup.bundle.js:797
```

Comment: Generally npm packages can't be used in a browser as is. Why do you need a package for `setInterval`?

Comment: @wOxxOm I practiced the basics and just wanted to learn how to develop an extension with an npm package as well. This was the first thing came to my mind and sounded easy

Comment: See [Is it possible to require npm modules in a chrome extension ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43684452)