# How to mimic node.js loading mechanism of node_modules in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I recently started working on a chrome extension project.

I need to consume some third party libraries and I am planning on adding their minified version to my project.

In node.js there is a loading mechanism that allow me to import any package in `node_module` without adding that path to the node_module.

I'm trying to mimic this [behavior](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) in my extension. My question is how to do it? I've read and investigated plenty in MDN and many other site but the only reference I found for this use case was in Typescript and in Webpack, which I cannot use in this project.

Comment: I think you can find some solutions in this thread [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684452/is-it-possible-to-require-npm-modules-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo in my thread, I meant I *CANNOT* use bundlers for this project.
Most of the suggested ideas talk about using node modules and undlers and I can't use both :/