# Request.js not working properly with Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, node-modules

I'm current building a js chrome extension, and to do so, I need to scrap data from some sites.

So, based in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575965/is-it-possible-to-develop-google-chrome-extensions-using-node-js) I found that I could achieve that using [request](https://github.com/request/request) with [Browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify).

I installed both using `npm` and created a `browserify.js` snippet to create my `bundle.js` file(*because for permissions reasons running terminal commands is not working*), so I can run `Node js` `require`'s in the client, my browser.

Ok, so I finally managed to create the `bundle.js` file and tried to run it in my local server, but it keeps giving me the CORS error and don't return a desired response:

> Fetch API cannot load https://somesite/index.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

One strange thing is that if I run the "unbundled" file direct from terminal using `node`:

```
$ node myFileWithRequires.js
```

It works as intended, returned the scrapped data.

What am I doing wrong? How can I scrap data in client using `request` and `browserify` ?

**CODE:**

**myBrowserifySnippet.js**

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var b = browserify();
b.add('myrequest.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const writable = fs.createWriteStream('bundle.js');
b.bundle().pipe(writable);
```

**myFileWithRequires.js**

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
      });
```

Comment: You don't want to use `request` on the client. `request` is too heavy (> 1MB). Instead `xhr` package implements a subset of request API, using `XMLHttpRequest`. Designed to be used with browserify.

Comment: Your problem is most probably related to CORS settings in `somesite`, not request. `somesite` does not allow request coming from another site, and browsers respect that.

Comment: @MehdiElFadil , so how can I scrap the data without this `request` solution? Do you have any idea?

Comment: In the browser, you can't scrape other websites unless the site owner is willing to whitelist your domain. Or you can use a CORS proxy, so that the actual request happens on your server side (not restricted by CORS settings), like [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation) for example. e; nvm, you're inside a chrome extension, then it's different. One moment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, XHR and `fetch` requests are bound by CORS, which means they cannot access resources on other domains unless those domains whitelist the 'origin' (the current page's domain). `request` in the browser uses XHR, so it's also bound by CORS.

In Chrome extensions, it's a bit different--you can configure your extension so that CORS doesn't apply to some domains. See [Requiesting cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) in the chrome extension documentation.

You need to add a `permissions` field to your extension `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.google.com/"
  ]
}
```

If you're not sure beforehand which domain you'll be scraping, you can use a wildcard:

```
{
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I wasn't already testing in the extension, but I will try and return to tell the results. Thanks