# How can i safely pass access token generated from Google OAuth to a NodeJS REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am creating two application : 
1. Chrome extension for gmail.
 2. It's IOS version

Now, since both the applications have same behavior and uses same google apis extensively, i decided to create a single project in google cloud platform for both. Now, when creating credentials, what will be my application type? I see both '**IOS**' and '**Chrome App**' under application type. Should i  generate two Client IDs for chrome app and ios app?

To use single Client ID, i also tried creating a Node REST API (created a new project and set application type to '**web application**' in google cloud platform) that will be used by both of my application to make request to google apis? But the authorization process includes, setting a callback url to get the authorization code and later use this code to get the access token. I guess this is not feasible for a REST API. Where should i keep the authorization part? In the application itself and later send the access token to my rest api? Is it possible?

I am very much confused about how should i start. Please could anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: Haven't tried your use case yet, but read on [OAuth dance in Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tut_oauth#oauth-dance) and this SO post about [Is it possible to develop Google Chrome extensions using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575965/is-it-possible-to-develop-google-chrome-extensions-using-node-js)
.

Answer (score 0):

I generated two client ids, one for ios and for the web. Isolating both applications is a good way to start. Both the apps generate their own token id, pass the id to Node Rest API and later the use that token to make a request to Google APIs.